# Include Maven Project into NON-MAVEN Dynamic Web Application

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I've included the Maven based project into my application, added Deployment Assembly which shows that the .jar file gets copied to `WEB-INF/lib/ImportedProject.jar`.

Problem occurs when imported lib wants to reference the lib that it is using which, apparently, does not get included inside the `ImportedProject.jar`.

Example:

ImportedProject `pom.xml` has:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I add ImportedProject.jar to my Non-Maven project and run it, I get exception:

`threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory`

My question is: How to add both that Maven project **and** its dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

[maven dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) helps to get required project library with it's dependencies.

So, If you would like to add POM based project on NON-POM based project, all you would do is to execute `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies` command and you will have all dependencies on `target/dependencies` folder. Copy all jar from dependencies and paste to `WEB-INF/lib` directory.

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow as I'm off work currently. Hope this works. :)

Comment: This does work but it forces me to do manual stuff and pay attention if anything has changed in my ImportedProject. Is there any way for it to be done dynamically? I don't want to handle dependencies manually.